# Create profile image upload feature

Tags: html, image, mobile, file-upload

I'm trying to add a profile image upload feature to my mobile app but i can't figure how to do it. Can anyone provide a solution?

Many Thanks

This is what i have at the moment.

```
<form id="profilepic_form">
<fieldset id="profilepic_controls">

 <div style="width: 120px; height: 100px; position: relative; background-color: #fbfbfb;   border: 1px solid #b8b8b8; "data-controltype="image">
  <img src="https://codiqa.com/static/images/v2/image.png" alt="image" style="position:     absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-left: -16px; margin-top: -18px">

   <div style= "top:50px;"data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="camerainput">
    <input type="file" name="" id="camerainput1" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
   </div>

 </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: basically nothing but i'm wanting to use jquery

Comment: i've added what i have at the moment. i'm using Codiqa to build with.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
 <input type="file" name="" id="camerainput1" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

You are using `capture="camera"` and device will not show you upload dialog, it will open the camera.

Remove `capture` value:

```
 <input type="file" name="" id="camerainput1" accept="image/*" capture>
```

But some of `Android` versions also open camera instead upload dialog, so the modern mobile cross-browser(Chrome, Firefox, Mobile Safari, Safari) solution is remove `accept` also:

```
<input type="file" name="" id="camerainput1" capture>
```

Now you have a dialog with uploading from `gallery`, `files`, any `host app` (dropbox) and `camera`

Comment: Now I'm solving the problem with `accept="image/*" capture` for Android 4 (Samsung S3, Samsung Note). This always open only camera instead of upload type dialog.

Comment: thanks for that, it's useful however my main problem is figuring out how to create something similar to what Facebook has for the upload profile picture?

Comment: i.e. selecting a picture and then that replacing the existing default picture. All the happens at the moment is i select the image and it remains a tiny tiny thumbnail image next to the choose image button

Comment: I don't understand your main problem. Can you improve your question and add all your problem code?

Comment: that's all i've got i'm afraid. i'm pretty new to this. All i want is to create something similar to Facebook or twitter's upload profile picture features...

Comment: Try [this](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic-plus.html) jQuery plugin. It make the basic upload very simple.